# Splitting footnotes

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I read a lot of question about how to avoid footnote splitting in two pages. My question is the opposite one. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \global\dimen\footins = 5cm
% \usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[perpage,para,norule]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[6]
At vero\footnote{\lipsum[1]} eos\footnote{\lipsum[4] }
et\footnote{\lipsum[3]} accusamus\footnote{\lipsum[6] } et iusto
odio\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
\lipsum{1-3}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to avoid the whole third paragraph is pushed over to page 2? So that not text but notes, rather, are split between page 1 and page 2?

============== ADDENDUM ==============

More or less, the same situation with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \global\dimen\footins = 5cm
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnote}
%\usepackage[perpage,norule]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[6]
At vero\footnote{\lipsum[1]} eos\footnote{\lipsum[4] }
et\footnote{\lipsum[3]} accusamus\footnote{\lipsum[6] } et iusto
odio\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
\lipsum{1-3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the package [bigfoot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot). It will often result in much better layout of the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which of these two results is the one you want, so I give both.  In both cases, the effect is done manually, through the use of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.  I don't see how this particular approach could be automated.

In version 1, the calling paragraph is broken up; in version 2, it is not.

VERSION 1

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \global\dimen\footins = 5cm
 \usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[perpage,para,norule]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[6]
At vero\footnote{\lipsum[1]} eos\footnote{\lipsum[4] }
et\footnote{\lipsum[3]} 
%REPLACE THIS
%accusamus\footnote{\lipsum[6] } et iusto odio\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
% WITH THIS
accusamus\footnotemark\ et iusto odio\footnotemark\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
%%%
% REPLACE THIS
%\lipsum[1-4]
% WITH THIS
\lipsum[1]
\footnotetext{\lipsum[6] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\lipsum[7] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\lipsum[2-4]
%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

VERSION 2

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \global\dimen\footins = 5cm
 \usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[perpage,para,norule]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[6]
At vero\footnote{\lipsum[1]} 
%REPLACE THIS
%eos\footnote{\lipsum[4] }
%et\footnote{\lipsum[3]} 
%accusamus\footnote{\lipsum[6] } et iusto odio\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
% WITH THIS
eos\footnotemark\ 
et\footnotemark\ 
accusamus\footnotemark\ et iusto odio\footnotemark\addtocounter{footnote}{-3}
%%%
% REPLACE THIS
%\lipsum[1-4]
% WITH THIS
\lipsum[1]
\footnotetext{\lipsum[4] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\lipsum[3] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\lipsum[6] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\lipsum[7] }\stepcounter{footnote}
\lipsum[2-4]
%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanx! I'm trying your solutions